# Is there any way of detecting if a method has been removed or a class has? Java

Tags: java

Basically I need to know if someone has edited my code, so there is an authentication system which checks the users IP and if say someone were to decompile it and change it so that it didn't check for the IP they could leak my code.

I have obfuscated it.

But say they deleted the class which checked for IP and the method - could I check if they did this somewhere else in the program?

For example, if I did `classInstance.methodName()` and the method didn't exist, would the program close? What would happen?

> Well actually, I'm pretty sure that there are some ways to achive protection by generating a hash code which takes your entire JAR-files into account. If you compute it and deliver it with your software (external file), then you have the chance to detect any changes. But you have to make sure that the "hacker" has no chance to simply replace the valid hash key by his own. This goes directly in the direction of encryption. You have to somehow secure your hash key that it's impossible to replace it without your knowledge... But I myself have no experience with this matter. Sorry.

This was a response - how would I generate and actively use the has, if this is possible?

Comment: If a class is deleted then all the other classes which have reference of this class will throw `NoClassDefFoundError`

Comment: If an unauthorized person gains enough access to the system hosting your software to drop in a modified version of it, then it's already game over for you.

Comment: @DarshanMehta so I could do a try {} catch (NoClassDefFoundError) right?  

JohnBollinger what can I do to prevent that?

Comment: I'd go with the answer of John Bollinger. If someone is clever enough to get access to your source code, you won't have any chance to deploy defence mechanisms that detect it, because this person will also change this classes and methods then...

Comment: @DiabolicWords what if they just edit the obfuscated code?

Comment: Well actually, I'm pretty sure that there are some ways to achive protection by generating a hash code which takes your entire JAR-files into account. If you compute it and deliver it with your software (external file), then you have the chance to detect any changes. But you have to make sure that the "hacker" has no chance to simply replace the valid hash key by his own. This goes directly in the direction of encryption. You have to somehow secure your hash key that it's impossible to replace it without your knowledge...   But I myself have no experience with this matter. Sorry.

Comment: @DiabolicWords thank you!

Comment: What if they spoof the IP?

Comment: @RC. how would they spoof it? They'd have to know the IP of a different user on another account. It's unlikely people would do this, especially as it could cause internet lag - and when playing the game this software is designed for, internet lag is the worse thing.

Comment: From my experience, code protection on the customer side is almost impossible. Any class could be decompiled, replaced, resigned, certificates reissued, calls to server  emulated by stubs/fake servers etc. The question is the user motivation - how much is user interested to get your code working :-\ You could try to implement some kind of `native-code` embedded protection, embedding some business functions inside native (C/C++) code. Another option is to move some business functions/calculations to a server ("cloud").

Comment: @lospejos I'm using JNA to get the current window - so perhaps I could look into that - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could consider is signing your jar file, and verifying it upon startup. Lookup signing and verifying classes 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/verify.html

Upon startup, you could simply look at the public certificate which is added, which is part of the signature block ( see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/intro.html )

This validation can also be done through third party software(generate a certificate through Let's encrypt, or an other paid provider if you're willing to spend the cash)
If that is valid, you can trust the certificate. If that certificate is yours, then that jar is signed by you. If you then verify the jar, then that jar must be unmodified.

However, this only protects a user from running a hacked copy *if he does not want a hacked copy*. Else a decompile, modify, compile will do just fine - who cares if it's signed.

Copy protection is not something which can be solved absolutely, only by obscurity. So yes, obfuscate! (and keep in mind that it's not 100% perfect)

I would do something like the following:

1. upon startup, verify that the jar is properly signed, with your certificate (might be tricky, but sounds doable). This is Class A.
2. have a couple of random threads. These are all different, and spawned at different times (and probably have some nondescript names which sound important.
3. Each of those threads has a plaintext key, an encrypted string containing the full name of Class A, and an encrypted string of a hash of Class A. Upon running, they decrypt the string with the key, use reflection to get the class of Class A, and verify it with the hash.
4. For further obfuscation, use reflection in your code at other places too from time to time, to hide the 'verify threads/classes'

As you can see, this is still far from perfect. Someone decompiling then needs to find all verify threads, and these should be mostly indistinguishable from other classes - so everything you use in them should be used in 'normal' code as well. And then your code becomes even more of a mess.

If I were to write this, I'd take a couple of weeks for steps one to 4. This sounds like a lot, but security is finicky, especially if you're not well-versed in it. Then probably add another 2-3 weeks to mangle my code such that the verify threads are indistinguishable - or maybe even have a small program do it for me so I have nice source code.
Then again, I'm an enterprise man, so I want it 'as good as possible'.
Maybe only step 1 is enough for you

Comment: I think the second half will have to suffice. I'll look into what you've said.

Comment: How would I use reflection? It has a lot of different classes, so would I use reflection to use methods inside of other classes? Is that what you're saying? And how would I do the hash comparison on the import files? I know how to make the threads and check every x amount of time.

How would I have a string instead of a type reference for a class? How do I encode that string? 

It's a lot haha. Is it worth it for this project? (http://nativeclicker.com)